# Clip raster data by multiple shapefile in ArcPy using Clip data management tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, clip, features, for-loop

I have one raster data of a state and also I have 14 shapefile in same area. Now I want to clip 14 shapefile in arcpy using for loop. The issue is when I run the script its showing TypeError:'NoneType' object is not iterable. Here is the code

```
import arcpy

rasterlayer = (r"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Mosaic")   
output = (r"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\clip")    
vector_layer = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(r"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\vector_data\\selected_district")


for vectordata in vector_layer:        
  arcpy.CalculateValue_management("\"%Name%\",.split(\"_\")[0]", "","Variant")
  arcpy.Clip_management(rasterlayer, "", output, vectordata, "0", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this error is because [ListFeatureClasses](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000023000000) does not accept a path as an argument, the wildcard parameter is used to filter the feature classes returned to only those matching a particular file name pattern, for example `'Edit*'` will return only the feature classes that start with *edit*.

You need to set your [arcpy.env.workspace](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000002000000) first, this will be the location arcpy searches:

```
import arcpy, os

rasterlayer = ("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Mosaic")  # file name needed here 
outputDir = ("L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\clip")    
arcpy.env.workspace = "L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\vector_data\\selected_district"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
vector_layer = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for vectordata in vector_layer:
    # the first part of the file name before extension (if present) then add .tif
    output = os.path.join(outputDir,os.path.splitext(vectordata)[0].split('_')[0] + '.tif')
    arcpy.Clip_management(rasterlayer, "", output, vectordata, "0", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Using the first part of the name of the input vector data spit by underscores and adding .tif to the end; ArcGIS doesn't require in many tools to stipulate the format, [instead it takes the extension and loaction and works out the appropriate output driver](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018700000009000000).. if none is given the result is an Esri GRID which can cause issues due to strict requirements.

Comment: I fixed the workspace as you told. Here I am using the Calculate value tool for specifies the name of output. Suppose I have 14 district each district has a name, so I want each output has each name as input file.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but this time error showing in clip. It is showing Execute Error: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution.

Comment: Is your rasterlayer valid, the path suggests an Esri GRID? 582 is a fairly generic error with *invalid parameters* and not very helpful, there are a few possibilities, the most likely is that your rasterlayer is a folder and not a raster. The next most likely is that one of your feature classes isn't a polygon or that the coordinate reference system is undefined. Output will occur in your workspace and as that is listed we can be sure that exists.

Comment: In above code you declare outputDir variable and in the for loop you mention output in both clip and os path. Please explain these.

Comment: Thank you now code is running perfectly