# ERROR 000582 from clip processes in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, clip, file-formats, for-loop, error-000582

Durring execution of clip in arcpy, an error has occurred. It is showing ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = (r"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\vector_data\\selected_district")

rasterlayer = (r"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\Mosaic")

output = (r"L:\\Arcpy\\Data\\clip")

vector_layer = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for vectordata in vector_layer:
        # the first part of the file name before extension (if present) then add .tif
        output = vectordata.split('_')[0] + '.tif'
        arcpy.Clip_management(rasterlayer, "", output, vectordata, "0", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Comment: Isn't this an extension of your other question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370463/clip-raster-data-by-multiple-shapefile-in-arcpy-using-clip-data-management-tool/370464?noredirect=1#comment605338_370464 just to be clear though is there an indent after for vectordata in vector_layer: as it was in my previous answer? if the next two lines aren't indented they aren't in the loop. Indentation is very important for python.

Comment: There’s much to be assumed here. I would verify the data you’re working with. Print is your friend. Ensure the arguments you’re using are what they should be. Your split seems odd but I don’t know the data. Can u pass an empty string as the second positional argument for “clip” or does that default to data available in your assigned argot.env.workspace? Ensure the data type man!

Comment: Thank you for valuable comments. I have 14 district shape file and one raster data. Now I want to clip 14 shape file using for loop and I want every output file has there district name.

Comment: Cool okay thanks for the details. Are there only shapefile data types in the directory you’re looping or other data types like rasters or BAG files? Are the shapefiles polygon geometry types?

Comment: Yes, this an extension of previous question. There are indent after vector_layer: here I typed wrong.

Comment: That's good, it really does look like the problem is your rasterlayer, I think there should be a file name at the end of the path. BTW I just noticed you're double escaping the strings, most of a time it's not a problem but perhaps try removing the r before the strings as the backslashes are all escaped.

Comment: All shapefiles are polygon and only shapefiles are exist in the direrectory which is in loop.

Comment: Your raster variable should be pointing to a raster data type. It appears to be pointing to a file directory. Ensure that variable is pointing to the correct full path of the raster u intend to clip. This seems to be a path issue. Also you’re rebinding  the “output” variable in ur loop which I wouldn’t recommend.

Comment: I have given the file name at the end of the path. This time showing ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000725: Output Raster Dataset: Dataset L:\Arcpy\Data\selected_district\Anugul.shp.tif already exists.
Failed to execute (Clip).

Comment: Set your arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True to overwrite your existing or remove the existing file manually, though a double extension isn't a good thing to have, have a read of os.path.splitext https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542596/benefits-of-os-path-splitext-over-regular-split try changing output = os.path.splitext(vectordata)[0].split('_')[0] + '.tif' to take the first part of the vectordata before the underscore and not keep the extension if an underscore isn't found. I'll make those changes to the existing related answer.